# Firebase Stream View number in API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

Hi I want to get `Users active in last 30 minutes` on Dashboard of Google Firebase Analytics by REST API

Is there any solution to get that number?

Comment: Hi, did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Any updates about this?